# How to refresh datatable from alertdialog in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to use an AlertDialog to add rows to a DataTable through a list of class values. However, the DataTable does not seem to be adding new rows when I add into the list of class values even though I'm doing it inside setState.

Edit: This can be solved by wrapping the AlertDialog with a StatefulBuilder.

AlertDialog function

```
Future<void> addAlert() async {
    await showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
        // the solution
        return StatefulBuilder(builder: ((context, setState) {
            return AlertDialog(
            //add-row to list
            ....
            

    }
  }
}
```

DataTable

```
Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return Scaffold(
    body: SafeArea(
    child: DataTable(
        columns: List<DataColumn>.generate(...),
        rows: List<DataRow>.generate(
            // items generated from list
            ...
            ))))
    ))
}
```

Comment: @Dani3le_ I've added some snippets for clarity. I am using the AlertDialog to allow the user to add an item into a list. The datatable is then built using the content in the list. Whenever I reload the page, but I'd prefer to not have to reload the page each time a new row is added.

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: @aoiTenshi yes I did. I wrapped the `AlertDialog` with a `StatefulBuilder`. I have updated my question with my workaround to the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait until the popUp is pop and then setState.

For example:

```
Future showPopUp()async{
   await showDialog(YourDialogHere());
   setState((){});
}
```

If it does not work with you, please share your code so it can be debugged in detail.

Comment: I've tried adding an await as shown in the edited post but the datatable still does not update.

Answer (score 0):

When you close the popup you can return a value and you can handle this value.

```
Navigator.pop(context, true);
```